# How to establish socket connection between two machines with each has no out-net ip preferentially using java?

Tags: java, sockets, serversocket

I'm creating some software which consists of a server and several clients, and I have a requirement that need two clients transfer files with each other.

Its workflow is described below:

1. A client(file sender) send a request to the server and tells it I need send a file to another client(file receiver).
2. The server returns the ip of file-received client and send a message to file-received client and tell him someone whose ip is .. will send a file to you.
3. The file sender create a SocketServer and tell server that I'm already ready.
4. The file receiver create a socket connection connect to file-sender.
5. File sender start to send file.

I've got a problem in step 4: because of the out-net ip, I can't establish socket connections from file receiver to file sender.

Here, out-net ip means that this ip is Router's that the machine connect with. The machine only have a in-net ip which assigned by Router.

Comment: If possible add some source code of what you've done already

Comment: Actually it's a project I will do. But I've got the problem 1 year ago.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Have you forwarded the appropriate ports on your router? otherwise your connection dies at the router.

Comment: No, I need this software install and run with no network knowledge need be known by user.

Comment: if you need a direct P2P-Connection, i think, there is no way to accomplish that, without port-forwarding. It is just physically impossible, the router wont let your packets go to the client.

Comment: I have ensure that it's impossible build direct connection between machines that under different routers.

Comment: unless I set the port-forwarding up. I possibly need a file-transferring server to do with it.

Answer (score 1):

Some time ago I created a similar application. If both clients can communicate with the server then why not to use the server as a bridge/gateway. I mean, the server will sends all transfers file data between both clients. You don't have to close the original sockets, the one created in step 1 and the one created in step 2 use them to do the transfer between the clients. It's just a matter of a well designed protocol, which, in this case, is not to difficult to implement.

Comment: I know what you mean, but this solution only fit for small data transfer such as message, sentences. But if I need to do with large file or large data, it will take lots of resources of network and load of server side.

Comment: Well it depends on what you need and want to do, a dedicated file server for this purpose it is not that expensive, and it doesn't need a monitor o graphic card neither a big hard disk, any old XP computer will do. Again, depends on your need.

Comment: thanks, I think I need a file server for file-transferring between senders and receivers.

Answer (score 0):

Your described way brings two problems.

Problem 1: In real net world you can find many configurations where file receiver can direct connect two file sender. You have a lot to configure to grant the access.

Problem 2: You make your code with that design to complicate. File sender needs to implement a client and a server socket.

IMO a better way would be file sender delivers the desired file to the manager server. If the file receiver want's the file he download it simply from the server.

Comment: The solution you described is the same with what ja_mesa says. But it will let server side in large loads if file senders transfer large file frequently

Comment: @Mrrain If the load on manager server is to high you can thing about a second file server. About what file size do we talk?

Comment: It's a good solution, thanks for your help. I think it must have open-source distributed file-transferring server on the network.